# How do I iterate over excel files in a directory, open each file, refresh it, save it, then close it

Tags: python, excel

The files do not seem to be opening/saving/refreshing.

```
for i in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\acct2\Documents\sales_reports\Rep Reports'):
    File = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    Workbook = File.Workbooks.open(fr"C:\Users\acct2\Documents\sales_reports\Rep Reports\{i}")
    Workbook.RefreshAll()
    File.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    Workbook.RefreshAll()
    Workbook.Save()
    File.Quit()
```

Comment: First of all, create `File` once, outside the loop.